# Why do i need to execute the statement twice?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT firstName , lastName FROM People WHERE born='1934'" ;
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
echo "<p>Execute the SQL-statement:<br><code>$sql</code><p>";
$stmt->execute();
// Get the results as an array with column names as array keys

$res = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$stmt->execute();
$res2 = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);




$ANSWER = $res." ".$res2;
```

If i remove the second `execute();` statement the `$res2` variable is empty.

Why is that? When i already have retrieved the results once/executed the statement.

if i input 1 as the parameter in the first `fetchColumn();` i get the lastName DB column, so the results are there already.

The reason i'm using `fetchColumn();` is that i need the result as string and not an array. I just cant understand why it doesnt work without the second execute, it seems like the result set gets destroyed or something after the first fetch and i need to execute it again? That sounds weird.

Comment: From the manual `There is no way to return another column from the same row if you use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data`

Comment: Have both rows, got both `firstName , lastName` populated? If your looking to select both fields from a single row, its working as expected.